# How to update the qty for id product is existed already in cart . when i add to cart it fully refresh and the new qty added

Tags: reactjs, redux, cart

this is the reducer part

```
import {CART_ADD_ITEMS,CART_REMOVE_ITEMS} from '../constants/cartConstants'

export const cartReducers=(state={cartItems:[]},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case CART_ADD_ITEMS:
            const item=action.payload
            const existItem=state.cartItems.find(x=>x.product === item.product )

            if(existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems:state.cartItems.map(x=>x.product === existItem.product ? item :x)
                }
            }else{
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems:[...state.cartItems,item]
                }
            }
            
        default:
            return state
    }
```

// this is the cartAction

```
import {CART_ADD_ITEMS,CART_REMOVE_ITEMS} from '../constants/cartConstants'
import axios from 'axios'

export const addToCart=(id,qty)=>async(dispatch,getState)=>{
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEMS,
        payload: {
          product: data._id,
          name: data.name,
          image: data.image,
          price: data.price,
          countInStock: data.countInStock,
          qty,
        },
      })
    
      localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

Comment: Looks like quantity is part of the payload item you are replacing in state. Can you clarify what the issue is? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The line that you need to change is this one:

```
cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
```

You are saying, "if this item matches the one that I am adding, replace it with the one that I am adding."

Instead of replacing it, we want to combine the two quantities.

```
cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
  x.product === existItem.product ? {
    // copy all other properties
    ...x,
    // add the quantity from the payload to the current quantity
    qty: x.qty + item.qty
  } : x
)
```